# UdpClient can't send many packets to different address?

Tags: c#, ip, udpclient

I need find devices in local network in some range of IP. Device can response on Udp datagramm. I do next:

```
var udpSend = new UdpClient();
foreach (string ip in list)            
   udpSend.Send(new byte[] { 0xCE, 0x56, 0x01 },3, ip, 33333);
```

There are many addresses in list (10.0.1.1 - 10.0.255.255).
But not all devices receive my message.
I tryed another way:

```
foreach (string ip in list)
        {
            var udpSend = new UdpClient();
            udpSend.Send(new byte[] {0xCE, 0x56, 0x01}, 3, ip, 33333); 
            udp.Close();
        }
```

But after 255 packets udp.Close(); begin very slow.

How I can create like udp scanner?

Comment: It may be more efficient to multicast or broadcast your udp datagrams. You probably ought to send more than 1 as well to ensure they are received.

Answer (score 0):

UDP provides no guarantees about message delivery.  The fact that not every packet get's delivered should be expected and you simply retry.  The comment about multicast/broadcast is a good comment; something like this is normally done through multicast or broadcast.